# Strange behavior y label in PGFplots

Tags: pgfplots

I've noted  a strange behavior of PGFplots y label with the following code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
compat = 1.3,
no markers,
grid   = major,
ylabel = $P_2$,
xlabel = h,
xmin   = 0,
xmax   = 60000,
% TRY HERE
% case 1      
ymin   = 0,
% case 2
%ymin   = 0.00000001,
]
\addplot[line width=1.5pt,red] table[x index=0,y index=1]{
  1.0000000e+003  2.7793697e-004
  5.5000000e+004  6.3359750e-007
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Compile with case 1 not commented and with case 2 commented and after viceversa to see the difference.

[image: the two results]

Can somebody tell me why?

Is it a bug?

Comment: I don't see any difference. Perhaps your `pgfplots` is outdated?

Comment: @romeovs. With the packages currently in TL2010 there is a difference (at least on my system). See the image above.

Comment: I have the same problem. I can reproduce the 2 cases above. scaled y ticks=false/true does not have any effect on the way the axis is shown when ymin = 0. It only works for ymin = .0000001.

Comment: @Matt: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question won't be seen by many people here so it would be best to repost it as a fresh question. Follow-up questions like this are more than welcome! Please use the "Ask Question" link for your new question; there you can link to this question to provide the background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a bit hard to predict when the tick numbers are formatted with a common scaling factor (as on the x axis in both cases, and the y axis only in the second case), and when they are formatted in normal scientific notation (y axis in the first case), but you can control the behaviour with the `axis` option `scaled y ticks=false` (or true, depending on what you prefer).